# Having links in a binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm binding text in `LocalizedResources` (for various languages) and I need to have links inside that text. Unfortunately when I bind it like this I can't have links in it:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AboutText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
```

So I basically want to make some of the words in that block of text links. Is that possible?

EDIT: I need something like this
[image]

Except I'm binding this text from `LocalizedResources` as I said

Comment: As for LocalizedResources - are you targeting Silverlight or WinRT? Can you also show how your LocalizedResources look like? Also how you define LocalizedStrongs.

Comment: I'm making a Silverlight application. By LocalizedStrings I mean resx  files created by Visual Studio for each language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Romasz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192454/having-links-in-a-binding#comment39242470_25192925) suggested, you should use RichTextBox instead of a TextBlock. You can solve the binding there with the following code:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=LineFormatted}" />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

For the hyperlinks, you can go through the whole text using C# and than separate the link from the text (you can use something like --- and than you know that whenever a --- appears in the text, you have a hyperlink).

Once you have a text and a hyperlink, you can add them to the RichTextBox using the following code:

```
Run myRun = new Run();
myRun.Text = "Displaying text with ";
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
link.Inlines.Add("hyperlink");
link.NavigateUri = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/");
link.TargetName = "_blank";
link.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(link);

myRun = new Run();
myRun.Text = " and with some text after the link.";
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun);
rtb.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
```

Where rtb is the name of my RichTextBox.

Comment: It could be much simpler if you had put Text/Hyperlinks in xaml and define binding for them - then the code behind is not needed.

Comment: This would be one of the better solutions -- you could also potentially build an Attached Behavior to your RichTextBox or TextBlock to parse out the <a href> </a> tags -- I've done it before with <b><u><i> tags -- was very straight-forward and simple.

General blog post with example of attached behavior:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgartner/archive/2009/11/11/wpf-attached-behavior-example-watermark-text.aspx

Comment: thx for the suggestions, I'll try them out and I can always change the  answer if i find something better :)

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward solution would be as follows:
Split your text into few chunks, for example

. before link 1
. link 1
. before link 2
. link 2
. after link 2
create textblock for every before/after link section and add hyperlink button for links.

You should be able to blend thgether these parts, so that user won't distinguish text and links

Hope this helps

That is the code:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20">
    <Run x:Uid="one" />
    <Run x:Uid="link_description" Foreground="BlueViolet">
        <iact:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <core:OpenHyperlinkAction x:Uid="link" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </iact:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Run>
    <Run x:Uid="two" />
</TextBlock>
```

Or:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20">
    <Run x:Uid="one" />
    <Hyperlink x:Uid="link" Foreground="BlueViolet" >
        <Run x:Uid="link_description" />
    </Hyperlink>
    <Run x:Uid="two" />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Could you provide me with some code? I'm not really sure how I'd connect all of that so it looks like a normal text!

Comment: Ok, after work ill provide some code, but its really simple using textblock run objects

Comment: I would suggest to use *RichTextBlock* instead of few *TextBlocks*.

Comment: @Romasz I wanted to use RTBs but I couldn't bind LocalizedResources to it. Do you have any guides for that?

Comment: +1 - Now WP8.1 *TextBlock* supports justification (comparing to WP8.0, where that was available only with *RichTextBox*), so my comment might have been inappropriate.